# How to soften edges of an image in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, blending

I have an image like this one:

[image]

I want to control the edges in order to gradually blend them, like this:
[image]

Is there a function to do that in Adobe Photoshop?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you are already doing it. How did you make the lower image and why can't you use that method?

Comment: Substance Designer. I have to learn it from scratch and I though that I could achieve the same in Photoshop quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by "learn it from scratch"?  What your image is showing seems to using a gaussian blur. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two different methods to dynamically blur the edges of a shape.

### Method 1: Gaussian blur a Smart Object

- Right-click the layer and select *Convert to Smart Object* to convert your layer to a Smart Object and enable applying filters dynamically.
- Enter *Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur* to apply blur to the layer. Press *OK* when done.
- Now a Gaussian blur filter is added to the layer. You can enter the settings at a later time by double-clicking the filter below the layer. You can now only edit the contents of the Smart Object layer by double-clicking it.

[image]

(This method affects every pixel of your layer.)

### Method 2: Layer Mask with Feather

- Select your layer.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and then <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the contents of the layer.
- Create a black solid color layer.
- Create a white solid color layer.
- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and left-click the layer mask of the white solid color layer.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the contents of the layer into the layer mask. Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to deselect. (This only works so easily because your image was black and white to begin with. In a layer mask the darker tone the more transparent the layer gets.)
- Now, in the *Properties* panel, you can dynamically control the *Feather* of the layer.

[image]

(This method only affects the edge defined in the layer mask, not the contents of the layer.)

Comment: It works! Excellent...thanks!